# Extract lines containing PAT1 but not PAT2 with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to extract the lines containing PAT1 but not PAT2 from a file. For example, with PAT1='dog', PAT2='cat', and the following input:

```
1 cat chicken
2 bird dog apple
3 dog orange cat
4 cat juice coffee
5 cow milk dog
```

I want the following output:

```
2 bird dog apple
5 cow milk dog
```

Answer (score 7):

Something like:

```
sed '/dog/!d;/cat/d'
```

See also

```
grep dog | grep -v cat
```

Comment: Grep is the first thing I thought of, is there another reason you needed `sed`?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this :

```
sed -n '
    /dog/{
        /cat/!{
            p
        }
    }
' file.txt
```

or with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '/dog/ && !/cat/' file.txt
```

later one have the advantage to be very clear & simple to remember.

or using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)

```
perl -ne 'print if /dog/ && !/cat/' file.txt
```